# Transitive closure of $D_r = \{(x, y) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : |x - y| < r \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone please provide a proof that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is the transitive closure of the following relation $D_r$ on $\mathbb{R}$, for $r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

$$D_r = \left\{(x, y) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : |x - y| < r \right\}$$

Clearly $D_r \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is transitive. But how do you prove that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq T$, for any transitive subset $T$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $D_r \subseteq T$.

This is exercise 1 c) on page 210 in Velleman (2006).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$ be arbitrary points and let $d:=|x-y|$. Then, there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $d<mr$ (yes?) and so you can find a sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^{m+1}$ with $x_0=x, x_{m+1}=y$ such that $$|x_0-x_1|=|x_1-x_2|=\dots=|x_m-x_{m+1}|<r$$ This implies that $(x_i,x_{i+1})_{i=0}^{m+1} \in D_r$ and hence, by definition of the transitive closure $tr(D_r)$, if follows that  $(x,y)\in tr(D_r)$. Since $x,y \in \mathbb R$ were arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I still don't see why $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq T$ for all transitive $T$ of which $D_r$ is a subset.

Comment: @ludwigmach I took an arbitrary $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times R$ and showed that it belongs to $tr(D_r)$. This shows that $R\times R \subseteq tr(D_r)$.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry about that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

For every pair $x,y$ we can find $z_0,\dots,z_n$ such that  $z_0=x$, $z_n=y$ and $|z_i-z_{i-1}|<r$ for  $i=1,\dots n$.

What conclusion can be drawn?